# IWebHost: Calling Run() vs RunAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, c#-7.1

When a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 project is created, the boilerplate `Main` method in the `Program` class looks something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run(); // BuildWebHost returns an IWebHost
}
```

But since C# 7.1, the `Main` method can be an asynchronous method returning `Task` instead of `void`. This means it's much easier to call an async method inside `Main`.

So the `RunAsync()` on `IWebHost` can be called inside `Main` instead of the `Run()` method. Something like this:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await BuildWebHost(args).RunAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

[According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost?view=aspnetcore-2.0), the `Run` method:

> Runs a web application and block the calling thread until host shutdown.

Whereas the `RunAsync` method:

> Runs a web application and returns a Task that only completes when the token is triggered or shutdown is triggered.

I was wondering when should the `RunAsync` method be used instead of the regular `Run` method? What are the practical implications of this? Would the end-user notice any difference?

Comment: Run calls RunAsync and blocks. Use RunAsync when possible, such as with the new async main.

Comment: @Tratcher source please?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/ad2fd9e4f59d81dc86620ee20f6cec0c205eef73/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostExtensions.cs#L59

Comment: Additionally, async main is just syntactic sugar. Behind the scenes the compiler simply wraps it in a traditional void Main and calls `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on it.

Comment: Which as @Tratcher pointed out is all `Run` does as well. So basically the difference is simply whether this pattern of blocking on the async method happens right at `Main` or inside `Run`. In other words, it really doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The default ASP.NET Core templates contain the following `Main` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}
```

That `Run` method there is the [`WebHostExtensions.Run` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostextensions.run) which is [implemented like this](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostExtensions.cs#L56):

```
public static void Run(this IWebHost host)
{
    host.RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

So this actually calls [`WebHostExtensions.RunAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostextensions.runasync), and just blocks on it.

---

Now, let’s look at how C# 7.1’s asynchronous `Main` method [is specified](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/c5fbcd6/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main.md):

> When one of [these task-based methods] is identified as the entrypoint, the compiler will synthesize an actual entrypoint method that calls one of these coded methods:
>
> - `static Task Main()` will result in the compiler emitting the equivalent of `private static void $GeneratedMain() => Main().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`
> - `static Task Main(string[])` will result in the compiler emitting the equivalent of `private static void $GeneratedMain(string[] args) => Main(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

So basically, having an asynchronous `Main` method like this:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await BuildWebHost(args).RunAsync();
}
```

Will cause the compiler to also emit the following:

```
private static void $GeneratedMain(string[] args)
{
    Main(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

And if you look close at what happens with the returned task there, this is pretty much the exact same thing as what the `WebHostExtensions.Run` method does.

So what does this mean? You can use either of these solutions and the effect will be the same. Your application will properly block until the asynchronous task gets resolved. There is no practical difference between the solutions. The only real benefit you would have from using an asynchronous main method would be if you had other asynchronous work to do in the `Main` method; although this would likely be very rare case since for web applications, you are more likely to do setup work within the lifecycle of the ASP.NET Core application (i.e. in `Startup`, and not outside of it).

Answer (score 10):

> What are the practical implications of this? Would the end-user notice
>   any difference?

There is no difference on RunTime level behavior.

> *Since this feature does not correspond to a CLR code change, **the async
>   Main method is just a syntactical sugar**. This design allows backend
>   compatibility with the previous versions of the language. To read more
>   details, please see Async Main in the Roslyn Git repo.*
> - [C# 7
>   Series, Part 2: Async Main](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/)