# What does IHost.Run() or RunAsync() do in a .NET 8 console app?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I've been following a dependency injection tutorial for a .NET 8 console app: [Tutorial: Use dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage).  The code in the `Program.cs` file is as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using ConsoleDI.Example;

HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddTransient<IExampleTransientService, ExampleTransientService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExampleScopedService, ExampleScopedService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IExampleSingletonService, ExampleSingletonService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ServiceLifetimeReporter>();

using IHost host = builder.Build();

ExemplifyServiceLifetime(host.Services, "Lifetime 1");
ExemplifyServiceLifetime(host.Services, "Lifetime 2");

await host.RunAsync();

static void ExemplifyServiceLifetime(IServiceProvider hostProvider, string lifetime)
{
    using IServiceScope serviceScope = hostProvider.CreateScope();
    IServiceProvider provider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
    ServiceLifetimeReporter logger = provider.GetRequiredService<ServiceLifetimeReporter>();
    logger.ReportServiceLifetimeDetails(
        $"{lifetime}: Call 1 to provider.GetRequiredService<ServiceLifetimeReporter>()");

    Console.WriteLine("...");

    logger = provider.GetRequiredService<ServiceLifetimeReporter>();
    logger.ReportServiceLifetimeDetails(
        $"{lifetime}: Call 2 to provider.GetRequiredService<ServiceLifetimeReporter>()");

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

My question is: What does `host.RunAsync()` do in a console app (as opposed to an ASP.NET app)?  If I put a break point on that line the application has already opened a console window and written its output to the console before that line is run.  So what additional functionality does `host.RunAsync()` add?

Please note that I'm only talking about console apps here, not ASP.NET apps.  I believe Run/RunAsync do different things for the different types of apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IWebHost: Calling Run() vs RunAsync()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455575/iwebhost-calling-run-vs-runasync)

Comment: _"When a host starts, it calls IHostedService.StartAsync on each implementation of IHostedService registered in the service container's collection of hosted services. In a worker service app, all IHostedService implementations that contain BackgroundService instances have their BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync methods called."_ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host

Comment: ^^ that's what the `Run` Brothers do. One sync, the other async. Plus waiting for an exit trigger.

Comment: @DanielMann: Thanks but it doesn't really answer the question for a console app.  In the example given that the console is open and the application has already written all its output to the console before calling `await host.RunAsync();` I don't understand what functionality `host.RunAsync()` provides.

Comment: If you haven't registered any of the mentioned service types, it does nothing on that part. So it just waits for one of the exit triggers. In that case I assume you only need the host's DI and config features? Then you _don't have to_ call `Run`.

Comment: @Fildor: Thanks for the link and the info, that's made it much clearer.  If you'd like to make an answer out of your comments I'll accept it.

Comment: For anyone reading Fildor's comment who isn't sure about the difference between a hosted service and a background service (like I was), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers#terminology for definitions, and https://www.site24x7.com/learn/ihostedservice-and-backgroundservice.html for a more in-depth explanation of the differences (including sample implementations).